# Salesforce : error while deploying Profile

Tags: salesforce

Profile error :

I am getting two kinds of Errors first time while deploying the profile. This is the error for the Admin profile.

> profiles/Admin.profile -- Error: Unknown user permission: ManageConvMiningReports

Next when I tried to deploy this time I got a different one

> profiles/Admin.profile -- Error: Unknown user permission: ShareFilesWithNetworks

I tried going to the system admin profile and searched for **Share Files with People in Experience Cloud sites**
and tried to disable it but that permission is default checked for the admin profile, and I can't disable it. So how I can resolve this issue?

Can someone please help me out with a solution for the above error?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the part of XML that mentions these 2 permissions, then try deploying. Or figure out how to enable missing features in the target org (experience cloud? Salesforce content? Whatever caused these checkboxes to appear in source org)